# passing variable from php tag to other tag in same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, tracking

I'm tying to show points in the map by getting latitude, longitude from my Database while the query is (`SELECT * FROM trackEmployee`) it's retrieving 
the data and show it on the map (Y)

But when I'm trying to set condition `WHERE groupEmail ='$mail' AND date= '$date'` by getting data in post it's not working

If I pass the value to the condition directly, It works (Y)

The problem here is to get the data from above php tag to the next php tag which contain the query.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Google Map API V3 with markers</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
 #map { width: 750px; height: 400px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
 </style>

<?php


$connect_mysql= @mysql_connect($server,$username,$passwor) or die ("Connection Failed!");
$mysql_db=mysql_select_db("GP15",$connect_mysql) or die ("Could not Connect to Database");

$mail=$_POST['sel1'];
echo $mail;  // prints correctly 
$date=$_POST['sel2'];
echo $date;  // prints correctly 

//On page 2
?>

 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //Sample code written by August Li
 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
 new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
 new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var currentPopup;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();



 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info,
 maxWidth: 300
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
 currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });

  <?php
```

//     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trackEmployee"); // this query works

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trackEmployee WHERE employeeEmail='$mail'AND date='$date'");


 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){


 $name=$row['street'];
 $lat=$row['latitude'];
 $lon=$row['longitude'];
 $desc=$row['district'];

 echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc')\n");

}

 ?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);

 }
 </script>



 </head>
 <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">


 <div id="map"></div>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do you know you have whitespace in ' $mail ' and ' $date '? And try to improve your security by checking the values of $mail and $date first before using them in the query ;-)

Comment: `mysql` calls are officially deprecated, please switch to `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: You have whitespace in your query parameters. Remove the leading and trailing whitespace for `$mail` and trailing whitespace for `$date`

Comment: I remove the space, it's not working

Comment: look at my answer below and try it.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I can only give an *educated* guess as to why it's failing, but my fingers are cramped up *Sam* - @JayBlanchard ;-)

Comment: Remove the error suppression `@`.

Comment: ...and your echos reveal...? edit: nothing, I'll bet.

Comment: when I set echo in the second tag the map not appear !

Comment: @Fred-ii- when using var_dump(); the map disappear

Comment: `var_dump();` belongs inside PHP. Your map shouldn't be disappearing; it should be showing you what's set or not.

Comment: Now to take out *the BIG gun*. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. I have a feeling as to what you'll be getting and that the error is in your form and possibly session not started. That's why your `WHERE` clause is failing.

Comment: the tags are correct if i change the query to  
SELECT * from trackEmployee; 
it works good , the map is showed with the points retrieved from the datbase

Comment: please be attention with me ! the normal query (SELECT * FROM trackEmployee;) is already works BUT the problem is to pass the variable from the post in the first tag to the other tag! #HELP

Comment: `WHERE employeeEmail='$mail'AND date='$date'` - `$mail=$_POST['sel1'];
echo $mail;
$date=$_POST['sel2'];
echo $date;
$_SESSION['email'] = $mail;
$_SESSION['date'] = $date;
echo $mail = $_SESSION['email'];
echo $date = $_SESSION['date'];` where is the session started? where are the POST arrays coming from? a form. There. show your form for it. I told you what to use to check for errors. I am done here. Good luck.

Comment: post arrays is coming from other page when i print here it's printed , while i was trying to get the value from the first tag to the other i t just try to use the $_session,,, anyway I don't want to use it,, I just want to get the data from the first tag and paste it in the second tag ! #HELP :'(

Comment: You use session variables but you never start the session.

Comment: okay! I don't want to use the session, i was just trying to use which would may work

Comment: @JayBlanchard please check the edit in the code

Answer (score -1):

Replace your query with this.Hope it works.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trackEmployee WHERE employeeEmail='".$mail."'AND date='".$date."'");
```

Comment: what difference would this make?

Comment: As far as I can see @Fred-ii-, none.

Comment: *Exactly Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: The php variable is concatinates as variable as '".$mail."'

Comment: we have to concatinate the variable for evaluate its value.Have you tried that query.

Comment: `'$mail'` = `'".$mail."'` - different in a way, but the same animal.

Comment: some mysql versions create problem with single quotes

Comment: As the OP has it the variables will parse just fine. [EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/svia-crkm)

Comment: @sonamgupta no difference

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the example but problem here with maps

Comment: please be attention with me ! the normal query (SELECT * FROM trackEmployee;) is already works BUT the problem is to pass the variable from the post in the first tag to the other tag! #HELP

Comment: Try converting this : echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc')\n"); from php to javascript .

Comment: The example was for @sonamgupta

Comment: @JayBlanchard okay :) please help me solve my problem :'(

Comment: *Nope Ralph* I'm not the guy @Fred-ii- and neither are you.

Comment: *Exactly Sam* - @JayBlanchard Those days are over for me.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what are you talking about ? I just need a solution for my problem